# what does Handlebars {{{{}}}} do?

Tags: handlebars.js

I'm trying to understand what does {X4 means.
theres an example on Handlbars site:
http://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html
the last example is:

> Raw Blocks
>
> Raw blocks are available for templates needing to handle unprocessed
>   mustache blocks. {{{{raw-helper}}}}   {{bar}} {{{{/raw-helper}}}} will
>   execute the helper raw-helper without interpretting the content.
>   Handlebars.registerHelper('raw-helper', function(options) {   return
>   options.fn(); }); will render {{bar}}

Comment: Hi Boaz, did you ever get this to work? I'm hitting my head against the desk over raw-helper blocks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33741905/handlebars-js-raw-helper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

data inside `{{{}}}` blocks are not processed and displayed raw (as is), most importantly **not html-escaped** (http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html).

example (just for illustration):

`{{{<span></span>}}}` outputs `<span></span>`

while

`{{<span></span>}}` outputs `&lt;span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;`

Raw blocks with 4 `{{{{}}}}` (http://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html) provide a similar functionality as above but for block declarations. Meaning everything inside the block will be output as is.

This is just a variation on the notation, i presume to make compilation easier since 3 `{{{}}}` tags have already a fixed meaning for raw tags

Another functionality this accomplishes is meta-templating, meaning a template can output another template code (in same language, i.e handlebars), which is then used as a normal template. For example from server rendering to client rendering (i think this [github issue](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/353) and [this](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/559) are related to the introduction of *raw blocks* declaration in handlebars)

Comment: Thanks Nikos but you did not answer my question. I asked about 4 { and not 3 {

Comment: Thanks Nikos, one last thing (I hope), do I have to declare a helper in order to use the Raw blocks?

Comment: @boaz, as far as i can tell no, they are built-in exactly for such cases (as metnioned in the linked issues). if this answers your question, you can also accept the answer.