# Handlebars.js raw-helper

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I have a handlebars template that works great. I'd like to be able to put the following in it:

```
<script id="someTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <div class="editStuff">
        <span {{#if aThing}} data-someKey="{{anotherThing}}" {{/if}}>
            {{aThirdThing}}
        </span>
    </div>
</script>
```

This obviously would render when the handlebars file is processed. all of the {{}}'s end up being blank, no good. I found the

```
{{{{raw-helper}}}}
```

block helper, and tried it out like so:

```
{{{{raw-helper}}}}
<script id="someTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <div class="editStuff">
        <span {{#if aThing}} data-addresskey="{{anotherThing}}" {{/if}}>
            {{aThirdThing}}
        </span>
    </div>
</script>
{{{{/raw-helper}}}}
```

but this ends up removing the entire script block from the HTML.

According to the [Handlebars docs](http://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html#raw-blocks) anything within the raw block should be rendered untouched.

I did try registering the helper mentioned in the docs, just in case it wasn't actually included, but that did not help either.

Comment: I'm not sure that a raw helper would help you here, can you add the data you send to the template? something is wrong there?

Comment: The data I send to it is irrelevant - there are no {{places}} to put it after the template file is initially pre-compiled. The raw-helper is not preventing the pre-compiler from processing the contents of its block. The output of the above block should be exactly the current contents of the raw-helper block, {{}}'s intact and ready to be compiled and used in my code.

Comment: I had the same result with run-helper... and it works that way in their sandbox too.

Answer (score 0):

You can just escape your mustaches:

```
<script id="someTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <div class="editStuff">
        <span \{{#if aThing}} data-someKey="\{{anotherThing}}" \{{/if}}>
            \{{aThirdThing}}
        </span>
    </div>
</script>
```

Certainly not the prettiest solution but it works fine.